# How to use pg_repack extension on Azure PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql, pg-repack

How to use pg_repack extension on Azure PostgreSQL?
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-extensions#postgres-14-extensions) is the link of with the PostgreSQL extension and while there is documentation for some of them, the documentation for pg_repack is missing. It is pointing to official documentation [here](https://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/) but I need to be able to invoke pg_repack from SQL script.

There is a related issue on azure docs [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/104541) but there is no answer.

All I could find is indicated in green rectangles in the following screenshot.
[image]

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Comment: @Spinettaro No, I gave up to this hoping there will be the documentation by the time we need pg_repack. Perhaps the following link may be useful, although it is related to google could https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74011157/invoking-pg-repack-extension-in-gcp-cloud-sql. Please let me know if you manage to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: @Spinettaro take a look here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/104541#issuecomment-1549969612